# insert or update on table violates foreign key constraint in UNO site

Tags: node.js, postgresql

> Insert or Update on table violates Foreign Key constraint in UNO site

Here is my Player `Table`

```
CREATE TABLE public."Players"
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"Players_id_seq"'::regclass),
    game_id integer NOT NULL,
    user_name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    is_host boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    is_bot boolean NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "Players_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT "Players_game_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (game_id)
        REFERENCES public."Games" (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT "Players_user_name_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (user_name)
        REFERENCES public."Users" (name) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

here is my User `Table`

```
CREATE TABLE public."Users"
(
    name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    pwd text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "Users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (name)
)
```

[image: Please see the Error showing in below link]

Comment: You should add the INSERT query that is throwing the error to improve your question and let us help you better.

Comment: $4, $8, $12, $16, $20, or $24 is not in players table.